# Intelligently decide on the correct SI prefix for a number

Tags: number-formatting, ms-access-2013

I have a field in my MS Access database for the length of a DNA sequence.

DNA sequences are measured in *basepairs* (`bp` or `b`). This is an integer value. However, often they are between 1000-10000, so it is sometimes convenient to use *kilobases* (`kb`) instead.

In my field, I want to enter the value as integer showing the number of basepairs. I want Access to look at how big this number is, and if it is smaller than 100, display as `#" bp"`, and otherwise divide it by 1000 and display as `#.###" kb"`.

If possible, it would be great if I could also enter some numbers directly as kb, and have Access convert them to bp, provided this does not involve too many keystrokes per entry.

Is this possible in MS Access 2013? If so, how?

Comment: Are you talking about how you want those values displayed in a query or something else?

Comment: @HansUp No, in the table itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For display purposes, you could create a separate Text field and use it to store the formatted value. For a table named [dna]

**id** - AutoNumber, Primary Key
**dnaSeqCount** - Long Integer
**dnaSeqDisplay** - Text(100)

you could create a Before Change [data macro](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/create-a-data-macro-HA010378170.aspx) like this

[image: BeforeChange.png]

so you could enter the integer value into [dnaSeqCount] and have the [dnaSeqDisplay] formatted automatically:

```
id  dnaSeqCount  dnaSeqDisplay
--  -----------  -------------
 1            1  1 bp         
 2           99  99 bp        
 3          100  0.100 kb     
 4          101  0.101 kb     
 5          109  0.109 kb     
 6          110  0.110 kb     
 7          111  0.111 kb     
 8          999  0.999 kb     
 9         1000  1.000 kb     
10         1001  1.001 kb     
11         1009  1.009 kb     
12         1010  1.010 kb     
13         1999  1.999 kb     
14         2000  2.000 kb     
15         2001  2.001 kb
```

Comment: Is there no way to avoid having two columns?

Comment: @Superbest Not really, if (as you mentioned in your other comment) you want the formatted values to appear in the table itself. Access offers very flexible formatting for numbers, but not to the extent that you seek.